# How to read every char between the string?

Tags: python, html

Hi I am trying to find the font color in python using this piece of code:
Style function contain all the html tags

```
if style.find("color: #3C3C3C")>=0:
    use_raw = '%s%s' % (use_raw, 'color: #FF0000;')
```

But here i dont want to make if condition with color specific. I want to do for all the colors

Comment: what is `style` here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to match on the kind of string you're looking for:

```
import re

def FindColor(styleString):
    colourRegex = re.compile(r'(color: #)([a-fA-F0-9]{6})')
    matchObject = colorRegex.search(styleString)
    colorValue = matchObject.group(2)       # Isolates the 6-character hex color value
    # Do any extra processing here, based on *colorValue*, and create your *use_raw* value.  For example:
    use_raw = matchObject.group(1) + 'FF0000;'
    return use_raw
```

Returns the following for any input color in the format you specified:

```
color: #FF0000;
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Are you getting an error, an incorrect value returned, or something else? Please be specific so that the community can help you further.

Comment: @RachitAgarwal - if/ when you get datHydroGuy's code working you should accept this answer